# next().closest().parent() targeting dizziness

Tags: jquery, label, jquery-selectors, closest, targeting

I have a checkbox input inside its label. I read this is okay to do. I also have a second checkbox nested inside that for absolute positioning issues. I have the inputs hidden so the labels are the click handlers. I want to make label-2 visible if label-1 is clicked, but they are in a list of many.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/tfKva/6/

```
<li>
 <label class="label-1">Label #1 (parent label so to speak)
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-1"/> // when this is checked (its label clicked) make label-2 visible
        <label class="label-2">Label #2
            <input style="visibility:hidden;" class="checkbox-2" />
         </label>
</label>
</li>
```

This is my code which isn't working:

```
$("label").click(function() {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            $(this).next('.label-2').show(); // can't figure out how to get at the second "nested" label

        } else {
            $(this).next('.label-2').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: take a look at the nth-child jquery selector: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: Then You need to add unique class or id  dynamically to the Input field and label (label-2), Next onclick of lable you will get that unique class or Id and then you can show or hide that element.

Comment: You should fix your HTML structure. Semantically this is a terrible way to go about it. Use a `<form>`

Comment: it can be simply like this http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/tfKva/8/ , looks like the hidden inputs are text fields but you add class `checkbox-2` for them, which is really confusing.